# How to include the HtmlSanitazationLibrary in class file

Tags: html, xss, libraries

I've installed the AntiXssLibrary nuget package which also installed the HtmlSanitizationLibrary. I can include the AntiXssLibrary with

```
`using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;`
```

then use it in my code:

```
`AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value, true);`
```

I've tried doing the same with the HtmlSanitizationLibrary but Visual Studio 2019 won't recognize the similar using statement. How do I implement/use HtmlSanitizationLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlSanitizationLibrary is tucked away in a completely different namespace even though it is installed with the same library.

```
using Microsoft.Security.Application;

string html_fragment = "some unsafe html containing XSS";
string safe_html = Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(html_fragment);
```

See https://documentation.help/Microsoft-AntiXSS/documentation.pdf, page 162 - 165.